# Create a formula for order of parenthesis

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, context-free-grammar, parsing

I am stumped at creating a formula (for a coded math problem evaluator) that finds what is within the parenthesis. It gets tricky when you have `()` within `()`, as it recognizes wrong.
 **It finds the first instance of a left parenthesis, and the first instance of a right parenthesis, and spits out what is in-between, then repeats**
Here are some examples:

```
(x)(y)   - works - (x) and (y)
(x(y))   - doesn't work - recognizes it as (x(y) and (y))
(x)(y)(z) - works - (x) and (y) and (z)
(x(y)(z)) - doesn't work - recognizes it as (x(y) and (y)(z) and (z))
(x(y(z))) - doesn't work - recognizes it as (x(y(z) (y(z)) (z)))
```

Can anyone think of a formula that will recognize it correctly?
1.First question, feel free to change the tags
2.To make it easier (if you want)
use `lp1` = first left parenthesis, use `rp2` = second right parenthesis, etc
3. Please ask any questions, sorry if I am not very clear (don't know how to explain it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Start from $0$, $+1$ for every left-bracket and $-1$ for every right bracket. Whenever it reaches $0$, you've found a complete expression. Recursively parse that expression and the remaining expression.

Comment: A formula for it...? It wouldn't work, see my edit

Comment: @XXXX: What do you mean by formula? There is no formula, just like there is no formula for sorting. And don't be so quick to say my answer doesn't work just because you don't know what is parsing or recursion.

Comment: Im sorry :( What is `recursive parsing`?

Comment: @XXXX: You can always check Wikipedia for "recursion" and "parsing"? Also Google "recursive parsing brackets" and read the first few results. Some will of course be too advanced for you now, but you should come back to them later. Say you're given "(()())()". Starting from the left, you get $0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,0$ so you know it splits at the zeros into "(()())" and "()". Recurse (do the same on each expression that you've split off) until there's no more brackets. For example on the first piece you repeat the procedure on "()()".

Comment: Mind = Blown *Watch out for question on `recursive parsing`!